# How make a button stay in over or down state when clicked?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, sticky

How do I make a button stay in its down or over state when clicked, and then back to its up state when clicked again?

Comment: Is it a flash component button, a button that you extended from the simpleButton class, or an entirely new button that you made yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import flash.events.Event;

var clicked = false; //Make a variable that stores the current state.

button_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleState);

function toggleState(e:Event){
    clicked = !clicked; //Toggle the current state

    (clicked) ? button_mc.gotoAndPlay(2) : button_mc.gotoAndPlay(1);
    //if clicked is true, go to the clicked frame in the button
    //(you might have flags, in which case, name them in quotes, 
    //butt_mc.gotoAndPlay("clicked")), otherwise go to the first 
    //frame (which should be the upstate)
}
```